# Change Intellisense Quick Info parameter font

Tags: visual-studio, fonts, intellisense

Is it at all possible to change the font/colour of the parameter in the Intellisense Quick Info tooltip box? If there's a large number of parameters needed I just cannot see the bold sticking out enough in the dark theme. I can see it better with the light or blue theme enabled but I prefer the dark because it doesn't cause eye strain.

What I would like is to be able to change the "float g" to be more visible while leaving the other parameters in the list the same. So it could look more like this:

Color(float r, ***float g***, float b)

[image]

Even if it's a bit of a hacky or roundabout way, I would just love to be able to change the size, colour or font.

I've checked through the font settings in VS but I can't find anything to specifically change what I want. I can make all of the Quick Info text bigger, but that doesn't really solve my problem.

Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: As I know, there has no such existing function or extension and we can file this suggestion through Help-Send Feedback-Report a problem to let the VS Product Team know. Meanwhile, you can have a try with custom the background color of the tooltip: Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts and Colors->Show settings for: "Environment"->Tooltip to see if it is helpful for your development with the dark theme or not.

Comment: @Sara-MSFT Thank you! Will do.

Comment: If you done it, would you minding add a reply or comment with your user voice link and we can vote it, the higher vote number can make the VS Product Team engineers pay more attention on it, thanks.

Comment: @Sara-MSFT Link: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/32216677-option-to-change-intellisense-quick-info-parameter

Comment: Thank you for your sharing, I will vote it.

Answer (score 0):

The feature I want isn't available in Visual Studio as of yet. I have a suggestion here:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/32216677-option-to-change-intellisense-quick-info-parameter

If you have the same problem or want the same thing please give it a vote.

Comment: new ticket https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/976964/intellisense-parameter-info-font-size.html